# Why $A-I $ invertible implies $ I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1} = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square complex matrix such that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^k=I_n$ for some positive integer $k$. I want to show that $$
I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1} = 0
$$.

I was reading an answer but I do not understand the last step. I understand why $A-I$ is invertible but how does it help me in arriving at the conclusion.

Here is the solution I am reading:

If $A^k = I$, then we have $A^k - I = 0$.  Factoring, we have
$$
(A - I)(I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1}) = 0
$$
Since $1$ is not an eigenvalue, $A-I$ is invertible so that
$$
I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1} = 0
$$

Edit: Added detail.

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(A - I)^{-1}$ on the left

Comment: This is not true as stated. Are you presuming $A$ to be nilpotent?

Comment: You should add nilpotency of $A$ to your premises.

Comment: This is not true even with nilpotent.  The matrix $A=0$ fails. Why does the first line of your proof start with the assumption $A^k=I$?  [And, why are you not questioning that first step, rather than the last step?]

Comment: Yes, my nilpotent remark is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you need to state the whole context of this problem, because the assumption $A^k=I$ has to come from somewhere.

Comment: If $AB=0$ with full rank $A$ then always $B=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that is $A^k = I$ given in the hypothesis.

If so, then the proof is perfectly good since the linear transformation $\left( A - I \right) \left( I + A + A^2 + \cdots + a^{k - 1} \right)$ maps everything to $0$ and $\left( A - I \right)$ does not map any non zero vector to the zero vector (since it is invertible). Therefore, the linear transformation $I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k - 1}$ must map everything to to the zero vector, i.e., $I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k - 1} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(A - I)(I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1})=0$ and $A-I$ is invertible, by composing by the inverse $(A-I)^{-1}$ of $A-I$, we have:

$(A-I)^{-1}(A - I)(I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1}) = I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1}=0$

Comment: how did you get  $(A - I)(I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^{k-1})=0$ ?